# Timezone in Google-exported .ICS defaults to UTC

Tags: icalendar, timezone-offset

I'm having problems with a Google exported .ics file and timezones. I have a list of events that I'm trying to get into a Yahoo groups calendar. As Yahoo requires an .ics file, I imported the events into Google using .csv then exported the calendar. The events appear to be correct in Google.

When I import the .ics file into Yahoo, the event times are in the UTC-0 timezone instead of the local timezone(American/New_York). For example, my test event starts at 9am in my Google calendar but after importing into Yahoo starts at 2pm. I've read about the Olson IDs and trailing Zs, including "Eric's Notes: Fixing ICS Time Zone. My efforts to apply this information have either had no effect or pushed the event back another 5 hours (7pm).

This is the .ics export of my test event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:iCalTest
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
X-WR-CALDESC:
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160118T140000Z
DTEND:20160118T160000Z
DTSTAMP:20160125T042448Z
UID:62el6loa5915gu9v9oja988enc@google.com
CREATED:20160125T042434Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20160125T042434Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Day of Service
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

What needs to be added / altered to get this event to show as starting at 9am in a Yahoo calendar?

Comment: couple of comments: `X-WR-TIMEZONE` is not a standard feature of RFC5545 so your mileage may vary while using it. As a possible quick fix you may want to check if adding a `TZID` to your `DTSTART` property helps, like  `DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York`, otherwise you'll have to add a `VTIMEZONE` component to be RFC5545 compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above event is a valid representation of an event starting at 9AM in America/New_York.
Are you certain that the Yahoo Calendar in which you are importing this event has a correct timezone setting ?
Just imported it in a Yahoo Calendar and it is correctly representing the event (3 PM in my case as I'm in CET). In other words, it does take into account my local settings. This is on a Yahoo Personal Calendar though, not a group one.

An alternative representation is to use local time with timezone, in which case you need to remove the Zulu suffix on both DTSTART and DTEND.

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160118T090000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20160118T110000
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the new direction to look in. I discovered that while you can set a timezone in a Yahoo Group calendar (which I had), its official timezone comes from the group owner's personal calendar - which is set to GMT/UTC. I've contacted the owner and will see if it can be corrected there.

I've considered your alternative but that would mean editing all of the events and I'm not sure it's worth doing.

Comment: Given that the issue is with the display timezone, the alternative representation will most likely not solve your problem anyway.